# UWP _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync() System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC00D36B2)

Tags: uwp

Like the title says,when i use _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync() func ,it throws an exception "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC00D36B2)"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make your question a [mcve]. Also check [ask] to make your post answerable.

Comment: 0xC00D36B2: "The request is invalid in the current state". There are several potential causes, for example, when your app is brought to the foreground and you try to resume the preview, you call this API without disposing the mediaCapture. As the comment above suggestion, you need to provide code sample & repro steps.

Comment: Have you check this official [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit)?